# Rails 3 Modeling Complex Has_Many Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm building a sort of message board system for gaming and I'm having issues modeling the relationships. Here's what I have so far:

```
Models
------
User (Has Many Posts)
Post (Belongs to User, Belongs to Game)
Game (Has Many Posts)
```

Here's what I need to add.

```
Models
------
Server (Belongs to Game but also part of Post)
Replies (Belongs to Post and Post's User but needs to function like private messaging)
```

What's the easiest way to model these two things? My best guess for Server is:

```
Server - Has Many Posts, Belongs To Game
Posts - Belongs To Server
Game - Has Many Servers
```

I have no idea where to even start with Replies. Posts and Users will have many Replies but Replies will have two users and a Post. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to explicitly model 'Server - has many posts'. In the application code, whenever you need to access the posts associated with a server, wouldn't you normally write `server.game.posts`. As for 'Replies', as long as you have 'Replies - belongs to post, belongs to poster, belongs to replier', you should be able to build all the queries you need, unless I'm missing something vital.

Comment: If you don't do Server has_many Posts, how would you access if the server if you just have the post? I.E. when displaying single posts, I'm using post.game.name, wouldn't it make sense to just use post.server.name?

Comment: You're going to have to do a `has_many` for the replies, there's really no other way to define that relationship.

Comment: @drderp So Replies belongs_to post, belongs_to poster (user), and replier (user), then Posts has_many posts should be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with these relationships:

Model Server

```
belongs_to :game
has_many :posts
```

Model Game

```
has_many :posts
has_many :servers
```

Model Reply

```
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :poster, class_name: :user, foreign_key: :poster_id
belongs_to :replier, class_name: :user, foreign_key: :replier_id
```

Model Post

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :game
belongs_to :server
has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy
```

Model User

```
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy
```